# shell script that lists files ignored by Git

Tags: shell, scripting

how to write a short shell script that lists all the existing files ignored by your GiT repository?

Example terminal session:

```
%> bash git_ignore.sh | cat -e
.DS_Store$
mywork.c~$
%>
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search engine results, and contributors trying to help will have to type-copy content when trying to analyze/reproduce your problem. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting. Also, it is difficult to understand what the `git_ignore.sh` you show doesn't already do that you want to achieve; please also include it (and desired output) in the question.

Comment: @Alex, the way to start this is to consider what command you would use to achieve this result if you typed it at the command line. Then you put that in a script and you've solved much the problem

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git ls-files --others --ignored --exclude-standard` to list untracked files that were ignored by the rules in your `.gitignore`.

See [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925079/why-does-git-ls-files-ignore-require-exclude-patterns) for an explanation of the options.